# WeakHashMap swap values and keys + better race protection

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap, race-condition, weak-references

Hey i want to have a WeakHashMap where the WeekReference is in the values or im looking for some alternative to this approach:

My current code to have a swapped WeakHashMap is the following:

```java
@Singleton
public class UUIDToResultSetMapper
{

    private final WeakHashMap<ResultSet, String> map = new WeakHashMap<>();
    private final Object lockObject = new Object();


    public void put(String key, ResultSet value)
    {
        System.out.println("current map size at put:" + this.map.size());
        synchronized (this.lockObject)
        {
            if (this.map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(element -> element.getValue().equals(value))
                .findFirst()
                .isPresent())
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("UUID is still in the map");
            }

            System.out.println("putted into map: " + key);
            this.map.put(value, key);


        }
    }

    public ResultSet get(String key)
    {
        synchronized (this.lockObject){}// memory barrier

        System.out.println("current map size at get:" + this.map.size());
   
        System.out.println("Currently in the map");
        this.map.values().stream().forEach((element) ->
        {System.out.println(element);});


        System.out.println("search for: " + key);


        final var resultSet = this.map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(element -> element.getValue().equals(key))
            .findFirst()
            .map(element -> element.getKey())
            .orElse(null);

        return resultSet;

    }
}
```

The idea here is that a second request can abbort the resultSet, from where i stream some data, but i need the end of the stream, so i can kill the data in the middle of the stream.

So each request get a transaction-id (uuid) and then the client can send if he think he have enough send a abbort signal. So i want let live the resultSet in the Weakmap as long the resultSet is active and not garbage collected.

Yes i now, i can put the data into a normal map from my StreamingProcessor classes, but then i have to be 100% sure that all of my ressources are within a try-with or something like that.

**So I choose this solution with the WeakReference. But how i can use WeakReferences for this not to bend the WeakHasMap as i did?**

And then some offtopic question: **Is there a better solution to make this secure against race conditions in the put-method**.

And **is there a nicer solution** to get my happens-before-relationsship in the get-method to **make possible changes visible?** (races are in this method allowed, so it the resultSet exists its ok, if not its ok too^^)

Answer (score 2):

A statement like `synchronized (this.lockObject){}` does not form a “memory barrier” (the Java Language Specification doesn’t even know that term), but rather wishful thinking.

Since you want to have weak values and `WeakHashMap` doesn’t provide this feature, you can simply stop trying to bend it and use a `ConcurrentHashMap` in the first place, to get real thread safety. Adding handling of weak values to `ConcurrentHashMap` is simpler (and more efficient) than trying to reverse key value logic.

```java
private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, WeakReference<ResultSet>> map
                                                           = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public void put(String key, ResultSet value) {
    map.compute(key, (k, oldRef) -> {
        if (oldRef != null && !oldRef.refersTo(null)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("UUID is still in the map");
        }
        return new WeakReference<>(value);
    });
}

public ResultSet get(String key) {
    var ref = map.computeIfPresent(key, (k, r) -> r.refersTo(null)? null: r);
    return ref == null? null: ref.get();
}

public void cleanup() {
    map.values().removeIf(ref -> ref.refersTo(null));
}
```

Prior to JDK 16, you would have to replace `refersTo(null)` with `get() == null` which is problematic because it may temporarily make the referent strongly reachable. The `refersTo` has been added precisely to avoid this problem.

The `cleanup()` method removes all entries of collected values. You could invoke this method within every `get` and `put` call, similar to how `WeakHashMap` does internally. But since `ConcurrentHashMap` is thread safe, you could also run this cleanup periodically in a background thread.

---

But this was merely for educational purpose, to address your question literally. It’s strongly discouraged to use this logic in real applications.

The problem is that the correctness of applications using this code will depend on the garbage collection. Putting a new value for a formerly used key will be accepted if and only if the garbage collector has identified the old `ResultSet` as unreachable and cleared the reference. But there is no guaranty that the garbage collector ran between the last use of the object and the attempt to put a new value into this map. Neither is there a guaranty that the garbage collector identified this particular object as unreachable even if it ran.

Even if the unreachability of a `ResultSet` caused an immediate clearing of a `WeakReference`, we still would have the problem that calling `close()`, which typically marks the end of use, is not the same as the object becoming unreachable.

So, to ensure that `put` attempts do not fail spuriously, there is no way around explicit removal of old entries before the subsequent put. Then, forgetting the explicit removal would be a serious programming error and hiding this error by occasionally fixing it if the garbage collector happened to collect the value, would make the problem worse, as it reduces the reproducibility. This makes one of those problems which likes to occur at the customer from time to time, but never on the developer’s machine.

But when forgetting the explicit removal is considered an error of the same category as trying to put a new value when there’s an old value still in use, you don’t need weak references at all. A simple `ConcurrentHashMap<String, ResultSet>` will do.